# 'A man told him how much he admired.' - Who admired whom?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I think the verb *admire* usually takes an object, like 'I admire him.'
But, in the sentence below, there seems no object of the *admire*. The audio sounds the same as the script to me. If it is a mistake, it's strange that the narrator didn't notice that the script is wrong.

> You mustn't mind your Uncle Joss. Some people find him strange at first, but he is very respected here. Just yesterday he told me that **a man stopped and told him how much he admired.**
> https://www.bbc.com/learningenglish/tigrinya/features/drama/jamaica-ep-02

Am I right? If so, is that an usual expression?
And, which is the correct meaning of the '*how much he admired*'?

1. how much the man admired Joss
2. how much Joss was admired

Comment: I think it's supposed to be 'how much he admired [him]' and I am not sure you can drop *him* because the verb is transitive.

Comment: It could also be missing an auxiliary putting the verb into passive voice: "a man stopped and told him how much he **was** admired."  In this case "he" would refer to Uncle Joss, not the man who stopped him.

Comment: I think the intention is that Patience was cut off mid-speech; she would have gone on to say "him" if she hadn't been interrupted.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I meant that if 'him' is appended to the original sentence, as Showsni wrote, I can see nothing wrong with it.

Comment: Yes, the transitive usage *A man stopped and told him how much he admired him* is fine. But if you extend that to *He said that a man stopped him and told him how much he admired him*, although that might sound reasonable in *speech*, most people wouldn't want to actually *write* so many potentially ambiguous pronouns in one utterance.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It is, though - this is a transcript from the radio play version of Jamaica Inn on the site. The actors are speaking slowly and deliberately, since this is meant to be for use in schools, but I think the intention is that Josiah is talking over the top of Patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the transcript:

> **Patience**
> You mustn't mind your Uncle Joss. Some people find him strange at first, but he is very respected here. Just yesterday he told me that a man stopped and told him how much he admired.
> **Joss**
> Are you talking rubbish again woman?

After listening to the audio, I believe that Patience's sentence is improperly punctuated. It should be "told him how much he admired..." to indicate that Joss has interrupted her before she could finish her thought. It's difficult to understand that as an interruption just from listening to the audio, because the pace of the speech has been slowed down to make it easier for English learners to follow along.

In a more naturally paced dialog, the word "admired" might have been interrupted, "told him how much he admir- Are you talking rubbish again woman?" but that would have made it difficult for a learner to know what word "admir-" represented.

Comment: This is the ONLY logical answer. And one can only get at it by listening to it.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said in the comment, the sentence is ungrammatical. The verb *admired* is transitive and needs a direct object as a complement.